# Spring Boot application - Invoke class with arguments without default run

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have these 2 classes:

***DemoApplication class***

```
package com.example.springbootstarter.demo;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

***HelloSpring class***

```
package com.example.springbootstarter.demo;

@Component
public class HelloSpring {

    String message;

    HelloSpring(@Value("${sbpg.init.welcome-message}") String hellomessage){
        this.message = hellomessage;
    }

    static String param1;
    static String param2;

    public void printHello(){
        System.out.println("Hello Spring!");
        System.out.println("and hey..." + message + " - " + param1 + " - " + param2);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class);
        HelloSpring bean = context.getBean(HelloSpring.class);
        param1 = args[0];
        param2 = args[1];
        bean.printHello();
    }
}
```

***application.properties***

```
sbpg.init.welcome-message=hellothere
```

I am planning to call `HelloSpring` on its own using Java command in a shell script with command line arguments but it seems to be not working.

One may argue that the right way of using Spring boot is to override run method in each component you write but in my case I need invoke only a specific component/bean based on the call in my automated job (shell script).

I am using `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

No luck with my Java command in the shell script...even when I am trying to test in my regular command line.

Any pointers or help?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code. It works well. Do check using dependencies. I use only this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The problem I am facing is while executing it.

I used this command

java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar HelloSpring "1" "2"

Expected output: 

Hello Spring!
and hey...hellothere - 1 -  2

Actual output:

Hello Spring!
and hey...hellohello - HelloSpring - 1

By default it is taking HelloSpring as an (first) argument but not considering it as the class to run. 

This is not correct. If I create another HelloWorld Class and try to execute it, I won't be able to.